# Can We get scrollable view for particular child layout in android

Tags: android, layout, scroll

Iam developing an android application where i need scrollable view for particular child layout which is scrollable if it possible please suggest below are pictorial explanation.
[image]

below are code for explanation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="android.xyz.com.xyz.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ntitled" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tp"


            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit1: For the clarification.

You can do that adding code like this in your .xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nreg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtReg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/val" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtVal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInsertar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ins" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnActualizar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/act" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEliminar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/elim" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConsultar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cons" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gaf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cons" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/asd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cons" />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok i will check in my code...but probably it may not work as i read somewhere that scroll is applicable for all view inside activity or except toolbar.

Comment: Ok, then you want only one child element of the layout is scrollable? For example a TextView inside of the layout? clarify please...

Comment: one child element may not be right but let say there are four linear or relative layout so i want one of them scrollable.

Comment: Oh i understand now, check the edit, you can see how i add a HorizontalScrollView for example in 6 botons (that are in a different Layout that the edit and text views above them) that obviously dont fit in my screen then you can view every button scrolling horizontaly, you can use ScrollView if you need scroll verticaly

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many Layouts, its not necessary, but anyways, doesn't work because lack one layout close like </LinearLayout>